# What does it mean by "Registering a Window Class"? Why is it needed?

Tags: winapi

In win32 API programming, there is a concept like "Registering a Window class".

It is done using the functions `RegisterClass()` or `RegisterClassEx()`.

What does it actually mean by the term "Register"?

Why is it needed?

Comment: This API allows you to create a custom window class (means group of windows with custom properties), register it with Windowing system and create instances of windows with that window class. This is most probably needed when you want to create non-rectangular windows or custom windows

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11808410/256431) is almost a duplicate, but its answers are definitely relevant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it necessary to RegisterClass in Windows API programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534141/why-is-it-necessary-to-registerclass-in-windows-api-programming) -- Note that even though this question is older than the one I linked, the one I linked has (IMO) better answers and is worded slightly better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a window is created (throw CreateWindow/Ex), it must be associated with a particular class. That class must first be registered with the system. MSDN simply states:

> A process must register a window class before it can create a window of that class.

It is needed because that is how the API defines it. The documentation does not elaborate on what goes on under the covers because that is unnecessary information for a programmer (and the exact implementation can change in updates). You are programming against the interface, not the implementation.

Comment: Why to register is important than 'must'. Please post if you find answer.

Comment: @PranitPKothari It's possible to use the [WINE emulator source](https://www.winehq.org/) as one possible (note: imperfect) implementation of the winapi interface, though it isn't the actual Microsoft code. I would hazard a guess that in Microsoft's implementation of winapi, there is a data structure in the OS itself that organizes windows by instance (i.e., dll or exe, for local classes), and then by name. [See this page for more information.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx)