# Registering Window Class

Tags: winapi

I guess my question is relatively easy for those of you who spent time dealing with Win32 API.

So my question is:

After initializing a WNDCLASSEX instance we need to "register" it using the "RegisterClassEx" function, why? Why do we do that? What's the meaning of this registration and in what cases I need to register things?

Answer (score 6):

The `ATOM` returned by `RegisterClassEx` uniquely identifies your "window class" which can then be referred to in other windows APIs. [[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633587.aspx)]

Effectively it is a hash so as to reduce the amount of data processed each time a window is created or looked for. It does also mean that multiple windows with same features can be easily created and identified.

I was addressing the practical reasons above. Hans Passant's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11809835/256431) correctly explains this is the OO class concept provided for C. [Further MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633575.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

The word *Class* in the function name is significant.  When you write code in an object oriented language, like C++, Delphi, Java or C# etcetera, then you use the *class* keyword to create objects that have *behavior*.  But the winapi was designed to be used from C, a language that doesn't have such functionality.  The RegisterClassEx() function is an emulation of that, it lets you create a window that "derives" its behavior from a named class, behavior that you can override.  With every window that you create using that class name behaving identically.

The WNDCLASSEX structure you pass gives a window its default behavior.  The most significant members of this structure are:

- lpszClassName.  That's the equivalent of the C++ class name.  You can later call CreateWindowEx() and pass that name to get a window that behaves a certain way.  Windows itself calls RegisterClassEx() to register several of its built-in window classes that you then can readily re-use in your own code.  "EDIT", "BUTTON" and "LISTBOX" are good examples of that.
- lpfnWndProc.  This is what gives a window class its specific default behavior.  The address of its window procedure that implement message handlers for specific messages.  You can further customize the default behavior, in other words "derive" your own class from the base class, by specifying another window procedure in the CreateWindowEx() call.  Such a window procedure must always call DefWindowProc(), the equivalent of calling the base class method.  Or in other words, a window has *one* virtual method.
- hIcon, etcetera.  These are the equivalent of properties of the base class, they set default values that affect the default message handlers.  Helping you to keep your window procedure simple.  It is for example rarely necessary to write a message handler for WM_ERASEBKGND, the hbrBackground member sets the default background for a window.

Windows requires you to call RegisterClassEx() even if you don't plan on re-using a window.  Which is by far the most common usage of the function in your own code.  You don't start to really take advantage of it until you write a library that implements controls, windows that other code can use.  Like "EDIT".