# Why is it necessary to RegisterClass in Windows API programming?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, user-interface, registerclass

I would like to ask why, in developing Windows GUI's using the API, is it necessary to register a window class? What is the concept of it?

I have already read the first 3 chapters of *Programming Windows* by Charles Petzold, but I still wonder what's the purpose of explicitly registering a class. Why would I want to do it explicitly? Why isn't it done in the background for instance in the CreateWindow() (or CreateWindowEx()) function? I mean, why isn't the code that RegisterClass() executes inside CreateWindow(), or why doesn't CreateWindow() call the RegisterClass() itself?

I have also been reading the documentation on MSDN and I know that the RegisterClass() function associates a window procedure with a window class, by filling a WNDCLASS structure. I know that this is the function that handles the messages from the OS, however why is it necessary to register that function (the WinProc one) to a class inside a separate function from CreateWindow()?

I can understand the reasons to exist the CreateWindow() function, and why it doesn't automatically shows the window created. This implies I also understand the purpose of the ShowWindow() function.

I'm sure that there must be good reasons for this behavior, to let the programmer register a class when he wants, I'm just failing to see those reasons, and that's why I am asking you guys to shed light on the subject.

Please keep in mind that I am very new to GUI development with the Windows API. I have done some GUI's in MATLAB, which being different from the Windows API, still allowed me to understand some of the Windows philosophy, specifically the purpose of callback functions. I don't know if this info is useful, but if you need to make some analogies please be my guest.

Comment: The class is a template. You might want several windows to have the same class. Not to mention it would be more complicated to do it in `CreateWindow` with classes like "Button", which are already there.

Comment: Well, the RegisterClass has what, a dozen parameters? (considering each member of the WNDCLASS(EX) struct to be a parameter.  And,the CreateWindow(Ex) has what, 8 paramers mas or menos (plus or minus)? Breaking it into two calls makes life simpler.  RegisterClass is only necessary to be called once for your own WNDCLASSes, and never for classes registered by the OS like EDIT, STATIC, LISTBOX, etc. Would you rather fill out 20 parameters every time?  I'm sure there are legacy reasons for when Windows ran on 16 bits and memory was paged all over the place.

Comment: I'm sure Raymond Chen's blog might have some interesting things to say: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873

Comment: The updated link to Raymond Chen's blog post [What is the HINSTANCE passed to CreateWindow and RegisterClass used for?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050418-59/?p=35873).

Answer (score 12):

Since you've tagged your question with C++ I'll give you a C++ analogy...

`RegisterClass` is basically you defining a class and including it in your program (much like a `#include` in C++). The `WNDPROC` is your handler for anything that happens within the window if and when an instance is created.

`CreateWindow` is conceptually the same as you doing a `new` in C++. You're asking Windows to create a new window, and you've got to tell it the type of window. Windows includes a set of predefined windows, such as Button or Edit, but if you want to create an instance of your own window then that's fine, you just need to tell it the "class" you'd like to create. You've already registered this class by calling `RegisterClass`, so Windows can now go straight to the definition and create an instance of your window.

Comment: However, here's my line of thought: When we use RegisterClass() we're not actually defining our class, we're just assigning values to a structure (which could be understood as some public properties of our class). The same happens when we use CreateWindow(), we just assign values to some other properties. In fact, if we think about your analogy, I believe it would be more logical to change the arguments of RegisterClass() and CreateWindow(): the visual aspects of instances of a class should be almost the same (think about buttons, and radio buttons), probably changing the size and color for

Comment: each instance of the class. However the behavior, the actions that should be performed by each instance, that's what will most likely be different for every instance. So my thinking is this: since the visual aspects (the template) should be very similar for every instance, assign some default values to those properties, i.e.: change the arguments of CreateWindow() and RegisterClass(). This would be more logical, at least for me. However I know that my logical is wrong, I just don't know where.

Comment: But if you think about it the size, position and parent of a window (which is set by CreateWindow) is nothing to do with the class of the window (as set by RegisterClass). Likewise someone creating a window shouldn't have to worry about which function handles the messages that will be sent to that window.

Comment: I can see that, if you are creating a control, it might be useful to associate the behaviour of the control with its window class. Interestingly enough, dialog boxes work the way you suggest where their behaviour is specified when they are created.

Comment: Dialog Box are from the class WC_DIALOG. The WNDPROC of that class calls the DLGPROC you provide, and is able to parse the dialog template passed to CreateDialog. You could do the same for controls, that is: writing your "Generic Control Class" and your own CreateControl function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to RegisterClass to define the style, window's procedure, that is necessary to program the thread that owns the window to respond to messages and events and do something or nothing for each message that the window receives and for each event that occurs, the icon of your window, the cursor the user sees when hovering over the window, background of window's client and windows's menu.

How can you imagine a window without all these properties?

Maybe you ask why all these window properties are not parameters of the CreateWindow function, so I set them with CreateWindow function and not with RegisterClass function, right?

If all window properties are parameters of CreateWindow function then CreateWindow function is **very complicated** and the line that invokes CreateWindow properly is **very long**.

This makes the code very large, less readable and less productive.

RegisterClass simplifies CreateWindow a lot.

This is one of the reasons that Microsoft wants the Win32 developers to invoke RegisterClass first before CreateWindow.

Also suppose that you want at least two windows with the **same** properties.

You allocate only **one** instance of WNDCLASS structure, set his fields to set the **common** properties of your windows and you invoke RegisterClass function only **once**, but you invoke CreateWindow as many times as needed to create all of the windows you want, but everyone with the same class name.

RegisterClass not only simplifies and shortens the code a lot significantly, but it also prevents duplicate of the same **large** code in CreateWindow.

RegisterClass also makes the code more productive.

This is an excellent design to first allocate an instance of WNDCLASS, set his fields, invoke RegisterClass function and then invoke CreateWindow function as many times as you want.

Although you need to invoke RegisterClass multiple times, if you want windows with **different** properties of course.

You will also have to modify the WNDCLASS instance before each call to RegisterClass function.

Answer (score 1):

I think the actual reason is due to system window classes:

"Many system classes are available for all processes to use, while others are used only internally by the system. Because the system registers these classes, a process cannot destroy them." Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-classes

Note from that link that many things in win32 that are thought of as "widgets" (such as buttons, toolbars, combo boxes, etc.) are actually windows, as in, they have a window class. These are provided by the system, and can have behavior overridden, but their default source code is hidden from the application programmer.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to think is because Windows is a closed source, so API writers do not want you to know much inside the API. So now, they think: "What if the user want to create their own window class with their own behavior?". That's why WNDCLASS is created for the users to declare the information of the class they need by assign value like names, procedure in the member field. It's something like filling the form. Therefore, you can see that API writers achieve 2 things:

(1) users don't know anything about the API, since they don't explicitly extend API classes to custom, cause if they do, so API writers have to provide the headers of the classes and users can mess up with that making Windows is not closed anymore.

(2) users still can define their own window classes.

Now, after you define your own window class, and you want to use it, so you have to register the class, so that the Windows OS know what class is that so they can maintain information about it for further need, and then you can create the instance of it.

Answer (score -1):

Each registered window is partially managed by the Operating System and to reduce the consumption of resources, both CPU and memory, it is better to keep the list of registered windows as small as possible. Therefore, separating the registering of windows and the creation of windows is a better design that combining the two tasks because users can create windows that are locally managed with just one System registered window class.