# ListBox created with WinAPI in VBA doesn't work

Tags: vba, excel, winapi, listbox

I want to create a ListBox in VBA with WinAPI. I managed to create it, but ListBox doesn't respond to actions - no scrolling, no selecting. None of this works. It looks like it's disabled. How to make it respond to actions?
The following code was used to create and fill `ListBox`.

**WinAPI functions**

```
Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Declare Function CreateWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "CreateWindowExA" ( _
     ByVal dwExStyle As WindowStylesEx, _
     ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal lpWindowName As String, _
     ByVal dwStyle As Long, _
     ByVal x As Long, _
     ByVal y As Long, _
     ByVal nWidth As Long, _
     ByVal nHeight As Long, _
     ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
     ByVal hMenu As Long, _
     ByVal hInstance As Long, _
     ByVal lpParam As Long) As Long

Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Any) As Long
```

**Creating ListBox:**

```
Private hlist As Long
hlist = WinAPI.CreateWindow( _
        dwExStyle:=WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _
        lpClassName:="LISTBOX", _
        lpWindowName:="MYLISTBOX", _
        dwStyle:=WS_CHILD Or WS_VISIBLE Or WS_VSCROLL Or WS_SIZEBOX Or LBS_NOTIFY Or LBS_HASSTRINGS, _
        x:=10, _
        y:=10, _
        nWidth:=100, _
        nHeight:=100, _
        hWndParent:=WinAPI.FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption), _
        hMenu:=0, _
        hInstance:=Application.hInstance, _
        lpParam:=0 _
    )
```

**Filling ListBox:**

```
Dim x As Integer
For x = 10 To 1 Step -1
    Call WinAPI.SendMessage(hlist, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, CStr(x))
Next
```

**Result:**

[image: WinAPIListBox]

Comment: try with `hInstance:=0`.

Comment: And exactly what you are hoping to achieve using common controls and low level APIs here instead of using MSForms' listbox?

Comment: @FlorentB. Unfortunately, doesn't work...

Comment: What about `hWndParent:=FindWindow(vbNullString, Me.Caption)` after changing caption temporarily to get a **unique search string** for your *parent handle*? BTW, I'm not experienced in windows API, but shouldn't it be called *`CreateWindowEx`* instead of `CreateWindow`?

Comment: @T.M. It *is* `CreateWindowsEx` - take a look at `Alias` :) And although `vbNullString` worked, the ListBox remained disabled.

Comment: Parent window receives the ListBox messages, except when sending directly to the listbox handle like in `SendMessage(hlist...)`. So I would take a look on the parent handle and if it is the right one.

Comment: Just an idea: Have a look at https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/194884-very-quick-question-userform-control-coordinates.html which uses `WindowFromPoint` to get the correct handle as apparently "the class name is the *same* for the **client area** and all of the above listed *controls (Frame, listbox, multipage)*".

Comment: @T.M., DrYunke Thanks for answers! Will take a look later!

Comment: @T.M. I followed link and read it. Well, I think you slightly missed the point of what is wrong. The problem is not with UserForm's handle because I do find it. Let's think logically: if I wouldn't find it, I couldn't create ListBox! But as you see, the ListBox is created and even it's filled with strings. My guide it was `Excel 2007 VBA Programmer's Reference` book. To be continued...

Comment: @T.M. Quote: *There are many different types of windows in Windows applications, ranging from Excel’s application
window to the windows used for dialog sheets, **UserForms**, ListBoxes, and buttons. Each type of window has a unique identifier, known as its class. Some common class names in Excel are outlined in the following table.* And in the table we see *Excel UserForm - `ThunderDFrame` (since Excel 2000)*. So, using all this, I do get handle. The ListBox is created, but why it doesn't respond to actions? This is the question...

Comment: Thank you for your remarks, I understand them; on the other hand my hint possibly reveals an innermost need to use the same class name for the Userform AND for the created listbox in order to get the listboxes default behaviour working after showing them (does different naming confuse the app?) - but this is no more than a  *supposition*.

Comment: @T.M. Didn't work... :(

Comment: @SMeaden I was talking to T.M. about UserForm's handle - not creating ListBox. There was a statement (in url) that UserForms are windowless and thus can't have handles. And this is why I referred to that book, where a handle can be obtained.

Comment: @SMeaden It's OK :)

Comment: @SMeaden You can read about handles on page 608.

Comment: Is this new list box window parented in your process? Doesn't look like it to me.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan : ah, you genius!

Answer (score 9):

Your listbox is not interactable because it doesn't receive the messages sent to the window. It seems that all the messages are handled by a child container:

[image]

To make it work, call `CreateWindow` with `hWndParent` set to handle of this container :

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim hWin, hClient, hList, i As Long

    ' get the top window handle '
    hWin = FindWindow(StrPtr("ThunderDFrame"), 0)
    If hWin Then Else Err.Raise 5, , "Top window not found"

    ' get first child '
    hClient = GetWindow(hWin, GW_CHILD)

    ' create the list box '
    hList = CreateWindow( _
        dwExStyle:=WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _
        lpClassName:=StrPtr("LISTBOX"), _
        lpWindowName:=0, _
        dwStyle:=WS_CHILD Or WS_VISIBLE Or WS_VSCROLL Or WS_SIZEBOX Or LBS_NOTIFY Or LBS_HASSTRINGS, _
        x:=10, _
        y:=10, _
        nWidth:=100, _
        nHeight:=100, _
        hWndParent:=hClient, _
        hMenu:=0, _
        hInstance:=0, _
        lpParam:=0)

    ' add some values '
    For i = 1 To 13
        SendMessage hList, LB_ADDSTRING, 0, StrPtr(CStr(i))
    Next

End Sub
```

and for the declarations:

```vb
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetWindow Lib "user32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal uCmd As Long) As LongPtr

Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowW" ( _
    ByVal lpClassName As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As LongPtr) As Long

Public Declare PtrSafe Function CreateWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "CreateWindowExW" ( _
    ByVal dwExStyle As Long, _
    ByVal lpClassName As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpWindowName As LongPtr, _
    ByVal dwStyle As Long, _
    ByVal x As Long, _
    ByVal y As Long, _
    ByVal nWidth As Long, _
    ByVal nHeight As Long, _
    ByVal hWndParent As LongPtr, _
    ByVal hMenu As LongPtr, _
    ByVal hInstance As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageW" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As LongPtr, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lParam As LongPtr) As LongPtr

Public Const WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = &H200&
Public Const WS_CHILD = &H40000000
Public Const WS_VISIBLE = &H10000000
Public Const WS_VSCROLL = &H200000
Public Const WS_SIZEBOX = &H40000
Public Const LBS_NOTIFY = &H1&
Public Const LBS_HASSTRINGS = &H40&
Public Const LB_ADDSTRING = &H180&
Public Const GW_CHILD = &O5&
```

Comment: This is fantastic! It works as expected! Thanks for screen-shot to see the what's going on and explanation! A little question: what is the way to listen to messages from ListBox? SetWindowsHook? Thanks! **You receive your award!**

Comment: @JohnyL, to listen to the messages, overwrite the procedure with `SetWindowLong` or (`SetWindowLondPtr` if 64 bits) of either your list box or top window with a custom one which will once the message handled call the original one. But since it's not possible to get the `AddressOf` of a method, you'll have to create the procedure in a module to then forward all the messages to a method in your form. Post another question and I'll post an example.

Comment: I have [posted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782255/listen-to-windows-messages-in-control-created-with-winapi-in-vba). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to call `SetParent` thanks to [David Hefferman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) for pointing that out.

So no need to subclass at all.

The Userform class

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function SetParent Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWndChild As Long, ByVal hWndNewParent As Long) As Long

Private Const GWL_WNDPROC As Long = -4

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
        ByVal lpClassName As String, _
        ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function CreateWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "CreateWindowExA" ( _
     ByVal dwExStyle As WindowStylesEx, _
     ByVal lpClassName As String, _
     ByVal lpWindowName As String, _
     ByVal dwStyle As Long, _
     ByVal X As Long, _
     ByVal Y As Long, _
     ByVal nWidth As Long, _
     ByVal nHeight As Long, _
     ByVal hWndParent As Long, _
     ByVal hMenu As Long, _
     ByVal hInstance As Long, _
     ByVal lpParam As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, _
    ByVal lParam As Any) As Long

Private Const WS_CHILD As Long = &H40000000
Private Const WS_VISIBLE As Long = &H10000000
Private Const WS_VSCROLL As Long = &H200000

Private Const WS_THICKFRAME As Long = &H40000
Private Const WS_SIZEBOX As Long = WS_THICKFRAME

Private Const WS_BORDER            As Long = &H800000 '* From WinUser.h

Private Const LB_INSERTSTRING      As Long = &H181

Private Enum ListboxStyle
    '* From WinUser.h
    LBS_NOTIFY = &H1
    LBS_HASSTRINGS = &H40
End Enum

Private Enum WindowStylesEx
    '* From WinUser.h
    WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE = &H200
End Enum

Private mlHwndList As Long


Sub JohnyL_Listbox()


    Dim lHwndForm As Long
    lHwndForm = FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption)

    mlHwndList = CreateWindow( _
            dwExStyle:=WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, _
            lpClassName:="LISTBOX", _
            lpWindowName:="MYLISTBOX", _
            dwStyle:=WS_CHILD Or WS_VISIBLE Or WS_VSCROLL Or WS_SIZEBOX Or LBS_NOTIFY Or LBS_HASSTRINGS, _
            X:=10, _
            Y:=10, _
            nWidth:=110, _
            nHeight:=110, _
            hWndParent:=FindWindow("ThunderDFrame", Me.Caption), _
            hMenu:=0, _
            hInstance:=Application.hInstance, _
            lpParam:=0 _
        )

    SetParent mlHwndList, lHwndForm
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    JohnyL_Listbox

    Dim X As Integer
    For X = 10 To 1 Step -1
        Call SendMessage(mlHwndList, LB_INSERTSTRING, 0, CStr(X))
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: If they are windowless, then how they can get styles with, again, WinAPI (page 622 of `Excel 2007 VBA Programmer's Reference` book)? Then how I *do* get their handles? It's not clear for me.

Comment: Maybe helpful for the conversation. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534141/why-is-it-necessary-to-registerclass-in-windows-api-programming.

Comment: @Ryan: I was just thinking "where is the listbox's winproc defined?"  The thing is adding listbox to VB6 form actually works.  So I thought it could be skipped here as well.  From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633574(v=vs.85).aspx, "Each window class has an associated window procedure shared by all windows of the same class. "

Comment: @SMeaden Thanks for answer! I will take a look at it later :) And if all is OK, should I use hooks (SetWindowsHook) to peek at messages for my ListBox?

Comment: Thanks for answer, too! Although code works, I think it's bit of hack. I don't know all the details yet (since I just started to work with WinAPI), but ListBox doesn't get white background as in Florent B.'s answer. Anyway, thanks for answer!

Comment: @JohnyL : ok, Florent will take you from here, he is a great programmer.  Thanks for setting challenge.  I have learned something and it has given me new ideas for my blog.

Comment: @SMeaden Anyway, thanks for your efforts for answer! :)