# UnHook Scroll Wheel from Userform

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform, mousewheel

I found the below code online (can't remember where), that allows the mouse scroll wheel to function in ComboBoxes of my Userform via API calls; the code works perfectly for that purpose. The problem I am having is what they call "Unhooking" the mouse, or returning the mouse wheel to regular default operation. Currently I cannot get the bit of code for unhooking the mouse to work, and it causes the scroll wheel not to function in Windows period, unless I close down the entire Excel Application. Can someone please chime in and help me figure this out?

**Regular Module code:**

```
Option Explicit

Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
(ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long

Declare Sub CopyMemory Lib "kernel32" Alias "RtlMoveMemory" _
(ByVal Destination As Long, ByVal Source As Long, ByVal Length As Long)

Declare Function SetWindowsHookEx Lib _
"user32" Alias "SetWindowsHookExA" (ByVal idHook As Long, ByVal lpfn As Long, _
ByVal hmod As Long, ByVal dwThreadId As Long) As Long

Declare Function CallNextHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long, _
ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long

Declare Function UnhookWindowsHookEx Lib "user32" (ByVal hHook As Long) As Long

Type POINTAPI
  X As Long
  Y As Long
End Type

Type MSLLHOOKSTRUCT 'Will Hold the lParam struct Data
   pt As POINTAPI
   mouseData As Long ' Holds Forward\Bacward flag
  flags As Long
  time As Long
  dwExtraInfo As Long
End Type

Const HC_ACTION = 0
Const WH_MOUSE_LL = 14
Const WM_MOUSEWHEEL = &H20A

Dim hhkLowLevelMouse, lngInitialColor As Long
Dim udtlParamStuct As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
Public intTopIndex As Integer

'==========================================================================
'\\Copy the Data from lParam of the Hook Procedure argument to our Struct
Function GetHookStruct(ByVal lParam As Long) As MSLLHOOKSTRUCT

CopyMemory VarPtr(udtlParamStuct), lParam, LenB(udtlParamStuct)

GetHookStruct = udtlParamStuct

End Function

'===========================================================================
Function LowLevelMouseProc _
(ByVal nCode As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long


'Avoid XL crashing if RunTime error occurs due to Mouse fast movement
On Error Resume Next

If (nCode = HC_ACTION) Then

    If wParam = WM_MOUSEWHEEL Then

            '\\ Don't process Default WM_MOUSEWHEEL Window message
            LowLevelMouseProc = True

            '\\ Change this to your userform name
            With SkillChange_Begin.Controls(Worksheets("Skill Change Detail").Range("AV2").Value)

          '\\ if rolling forward increase Top index by 1 to cause an Up Scroll
            If GetHookStruct(lParam).mouseData > 0 Then

                .TopIndex = intTopIndex - 1

                '\\ Store new TopIndex value
                intTopIndex = .TopIndex

            Else '\\ if rolling backward decrease Top index by 1 to cause _
            '\\a Down Scroll

                .TopIndex = intTopIndex + 1

                '\\ Store new TopIndex value
                intTopIndex = .TopIndex

            End If

       End With

    End If

    Exit Function

End If

LowLevelMouseProc = CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, ByVal lParam)
End Function
'=======================================================================
Sub Hook_Mouse()

hhkLowLevelMouse = SetWindowsHookEx _
(WH_MOUSE_LL, AddressOf LowLevelMouseProc, Application.Hinstance, 0)

End Sub

'========================================================================
Sub UnHook_Mouse()

If hhkLowLevelMouse <> 0 Then UnhookWindowsHookEx hhkLowLevelMouse

End Sub
```

**Userform Code:**

```
Private Sub Skill1_1_DropButtonClick()

Worksheets("Skill Change Detail").Range("AV2").Value = SkillChange_Begin.Frame31.ActiveControl.Name
intTopIndex = Skill1_1.TopIndex
Hook_Mouse

End Sub

 Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()

UnHook_Mouse

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be easier and more manageable to intercept the messages from the message loop of the form. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782255/listen-to-windows-messages-in-control-created-with-winapi-in-vba/48794143#48794143

Comment: Alternative solution: [VBA UserForm MouseScroll](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-UserForm-MouseScroll)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon further research of the inner workings of these API calls, I discovered that the SetWindowsHookEx function sets a hook in place to monitor the mouse usage; this hook is deemed by a numeric value. In order to remove this hook, you must use the complimentary UnhookWindowsHookEx function and the numeric value assigned during the initial hook with the SetWindowsHookEx function.  There is no way of knowing this numeric value (that I could figure out) in order to release the hook, so I just devised the simple code below which does the trick:

```
Sub UnHook_Mouse()

Dim L1 As Long

For L1 = 1 To 10000
    UnhookWindowsHookEx L1
Next L1

End Sub
```