# Is it possible to get information about the email an attachment on the clipboard came from?

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, clipboard

I've been working on Access VBA code to allow users to copy and "paste" (via a button) files, Outlook messages, and Outlook attachments interchangeably, where the pasted files or emails (it actually just looks at the currently selected emails rather than the clipboard in that scenario) populate an array or selection that the database can then work through.

Because users are unpredictable, I'm worried about a scenario where someone doesn't "paste" an attachment right away, and moves on to a different email before they click the Paste button, especially if that new email has an attachment with the same filename.

I adapted the API code from here (https://www.access-o-mania.de/forum/index.php?topic=17045.15) to get the attachment filenames from the clipboard, but is there any way to get identifying information for the email they came from as well, preferably something truly unique like EntryID (which my code needs anyway)?

Comment: I don't think this info is on the clipboard, but haven't checked thoroughly. As a (sketchy) workaround, you can create a window, register it as the clipboard viewer so it gets a message whenever the clipboard changes using [SetClipboardViewer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setclipboardviewer), then detect if at that time Outlook was the active window, if so log the current open outlook item to a variable using a window proc. See [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48794143)

Comment: Very interesting. I will probably look at AddClipboardFormatListener as well. Thanks!

Comment: If I can get that to work, I can also use it to trigger a check of the clipboard format and then enable or disable the "paste" button accordingly.

Comment: To the closers, this evidently is not a debugging question, so steps to reproduce a "problem" aren't needed. Summarized, it asks the following: if an outlook attachment is on the clipboard, how do I reliably determine which mail it was copied from? That's an on-topic, clear and narrowly-defined question, very niche but that's allowed.